# Dynamically accessing vuex data in v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, v-for

Is it possible to access vuex data dynamically in a `v-for` within a template?

I tried accessing it with the `$data` variable in the template without success:

```html
<template>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in items">
        {{item.id}}: {{$data[item.value]}}<br>        
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "test",
        data: () => ({
            items: [
                {id: 'item1', value: "countingDice"},
                {id: 'item2', value: "otherValue"},
            ],
        }),
        computed: {
            ...mapState("countingDice"),
            ...mapGetters("otherValue"),
        }
    }
</script>
```

The vuex data is injected with a `mapState` and a `mapGetter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a method `getState` as follows :

```
<template>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in items">
        {{item.id}}: {{getState(item.value)}}<br>        
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: "test",
        data: () => ({
            items: [
                {id: 'item1', value: "countingDice"},
                {id: 'item2', value: "otherValue"},
            ],
        }),
        computed: {
            ...mapState("countingDice"),
            ...mapGetters("otherValue"),
        },
     methods:{
       getState(val){
      return this[val]; // this returns the computed property with val as name
      }
     }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This works! At first I thought you would loose reactivity of the values but apparently vuejs is smart enough